# Определить количество элементов, равных среднему значению

Tags: pascal, массивы

Дан одномерный массив S(N). Определить количество элементов, равных среднему значению. Заменить эти элементы на 100.

Comment: @ehometop, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 6):

1. [Как находить среднее значение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5)
2. [Работа с массивами](http://www.pascal.helpov.net/index/one-dimensional_arrays_pascal_programming)
3. Поисковики, которыми можно воспользоваться, чтобы найти ответы на большинство вопросов: [Яндекс](http://www.yandex.ru/), [Гугл](https://www.google.ru/), [Спутник](http://www.sputnik.ru/) *лол**

лол потому что с++ там [популяризируется котиками](http://pics.sputnik.ru/search?q=C%2B%2B)

Comment: Я бы не стал рекламировать этот чудо-поисковик Спутник человеку, который хочет заниматься программированием. Насколько мне известно, он работает только для дорогих россиян, не особо хорошо (пока во всяком случае) ищет, и вообще по словам создателей не очень предназначен для поиска по зарубежным ресурсам (для вопросов, связанных с программированием это критично). Ваш пример с котиками про запросу С++ более чем показателен
В общем, больше походит на очередной отечественный распил, нежели на серьезный продукт

Answer (score 3):

1. Вычисляем среднее значение.
2. Пробегаем по массиву, заменяем среднее значение на 100.

Comment: а можно код?

Comment: А какие проблемы с его написанием?

Comment: @ehometop не нужно здесь просить сделать за вас работу - такие вопросы тут не приветствуются и закрываются. Если вы что-то сделали сами - показывайте

Comment: Нельзя код.

Comment: @ehometop Могу привести год на C#! Нужно?